# Trying to display image from database in datagrid column Exception "The component cannot be found"

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to display a varbinary image from database, i'm converting it to byte[] with this code

**Filme.cs**

```cs
if (row["foto"] != DBNull.Value)
                    f.Foto = (byte[])row["foto"];
```

and this is how i'm choosing the file to send to the database

**GestaoDeFilmesViewModel.cs**

```
public async static Task<StorageFile> OpenLocalFile(params string[] types)
        {
            var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
            picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
            Regex typeReg = new Regex(@"^\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                if (type == "*" || typeReg.IsMatch(type))
                    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(type);
                else
                    throw new InvalidCastException("A extensão do ficheiro está incorreta");
            }
            var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
                return file;
            else
                return null;
        }
```

and then sending it like this

**GestaoDeFilmesViewModel.cs**

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateFoto(StorageFile file)
        {
            if (file == null)
                return false;
            SelectedFilme.Foto = (await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file)).ToArray();
            if(SelectedFilme.Foto == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (SelectedFilme.UpdateFoto() == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

this is the user control i'm using to convert the image from byte[] to BitMapImage

**FotoControl.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="MyMovies.universal.UserControl.FotoControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyMovies.universal.UserControl"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="Foto"></Image>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

here is the code behind, an exception is thrown in Source_Changed method, i'll post a picture about it

**FotoControl.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class FotoControl : UserControl
    {
        public FotoControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        public byte[] ImageSource
        {
            get { return (byte[])GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(byte[]), typeof(UserControlFolder.FotoControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(Source_Changed)));

        private static async void Source_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue != null && e.NewValue is byte[] data)
            {
                var instance = d as FotoControl;
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
                {
                    await stream.WriteAsync(data.AsBuffer());
                    await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                }
                instance.Foto.Source = image;
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the page where i'm showing the image, after the conversion

**GestaoDeFilmes.xaml**

```xml
<control:FotoControl ImageSource="{Binding Foto, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

[image: Exception]
[image: Foto isn't null]

You can see by the debug image that Foto has content, isn't null.
I think the exception has something to do with Windows not being able to decode the image from what other people said.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you translate exception message? And write it directly in question, not only in the screen?

Comment: Please check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5cb7ecf-3f04-42ac-815e-c104582ab8ac/uwpconvert-byte-array-to-windowsuixamlmediaimagingbitmapimage?forum=wpdevelop). you seem to be miss   `stream.Seek(0);`

Comment: i'm sorry, i forgot to translate it

Comment: thanks a lot @NicoZhu-MSFT, it worked, can you post that as an answer? so i can accept the answer to help other people with the same problem? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5cb7ecf-3f04-42ac-815e-c104582ab8ac/uwpconvert-byte-array-to-windowsuixamlmediaimagingbitmapimage?forum=wpdevelop). you seem to be miss `stream.Seek(0)`

```
public async static Task<BitmapImage> ImageFromBytes(Byte[] bytes)
{
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        await stream.WriteAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());
        stream.Seek(0);
        await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
    }
    return image;
}
```